# Routing control feature

Tags: networking, router, routing

I am not sure what this feature is called or how to ask if a router has it or not, so I will describe it with the hope someone can tell me what it would be called,

I have a network with two routers, currently you can join either network/router and have access to all resources on both networks, what I want to do is limit one of the networks to only access a single IP address on the other routers network.

I have gone through the configuration on both routers and am guessing they simply do not have these types of routing features\control, but I need to know what it is called so I can get a router that allows this type of configuration.

thanks

Comment: Do your routers support custom routes? IE Can you say I want to forward 192.168.1.15/26 to this IP addr/Interface?

Comment: There is a lot of information missing from this question. Firstly what are the routers in question and how are they connected together? How are the IP addresses configured? I assume that you have all machines on the same subnet. If so, you are not talking about routing, but rather switching. I think that what you are after is more of a firewall configuration or access control on one of the routers.

Comment: From the manual and the setup screens the routers do not support 'custom routing'